# Java: Check if otf font file contains small caps glyphs

Tags: java, opentype, smallcaps

Is there a way to check if otf font file contains glyphs for small caps variation?
Is there a way to do it in java?

Thanks!

Comment: Display text using the font and visually verify if it meets your needs.  Maybe something like a [font selector](https://github.com/ggleblanc2/font-selector)?

Comment: That's a really stupid piece of advice. Just run the font through literally any half-decent font engine/checker and check if it supports [the `smcp` feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/opentype/spec/features_pt#tag-smcp). The whole point of the OpenType spec is that you can check for features without "displaying text" first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is, just don't use standard-library-Java for it. Use either a Java OpenType font analyser, or do the more sensible thing and consult Freetype2 or Harfbuzz for that information.

Really, anything that lets you check OpenType features will do: check whether the font encodes for the [smcp feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/opentype/spec/features_pt#tag-smcp) - if it does, it support proper smallcaps as per the OpenType spec. If not, it doesn't, and whatever text engine you're using is going to fake it.